# Replace a word using different files Bash

Tags: bash, sed, replace, find

im looking to edit my 1.txt file, to find a word and replace it with the correspondant word in 2.txt and also add the rest of the string of file 2.

Im interest in maintain the order of my 1.txt file.

```
>title1
ID1 .... rest of string im not interested
>title2
ID2 .... rest of string im not interested
>title3
ID3 .... rest of string im not interested
>title....
```

But I want to add the information of my file 2

```
>ID1  text i want to extract
>ID2  text i want to extract
>ID3  text i want to extract
>IDs....
```

At the end im looking to create a new file with this structure

```
>title1
ID1 .... text I want
>title2
ID2 .... text I want
>title3
ID3 .... text I want
>title....
```

I have tried several sed commands, but most of them dont replace the ID# exactly for the one
that is in the two files. Hopefully it could be done in bash

Thanks for your help

Failed atempts..
my codes are
File 1 = cog_anotations.txt, File 2=Real.cog.txt
ID= COG05764, COG 015668, etc...

```
sed -e '/COG/{r Real.cog.txt' -e 'd}' cog_anotations.txt
sed "s/^.*COG.*$/$(cat Real.cog.txt)/" cog_anotations.txt
sed -e '/\$COG\$/{r Real.cog.txt'  -e 'd}' cog_anotations.txt
grep -F -f cog_anotations.txt Real.cog.txt > newfile.txt
grep -F -f Real.cog.txt cog_anotations.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: Show us your failed attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file.awk :

```
BEGIN { RS=">" }
{ 
  if (FILENAME == "1.txt") {
    a[$2]=$1; b[$2]=$2; 
  } 
  else { 
      if ($1 == b[$1]) {
        if ($1 !="") { printf(">%s\n%s",a[$1],$0) } 
      }
  }
}
```

call:

```
gawk -f file.awk 1.txt 2.txt
```

*The order of files is important.*

result:

```
>title1
ID1  text i want to extract
>title2
ID2  text i want to extract
>title3
ID3  text i want to extract
```

explanation:

The first file is divided into records at the ">" place and then two associative arrays are created. Only the else body is performed for the second file. Next we check if field 1 of the second file is in table b and if so format and print the next lines.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT write some nested grep.
A simplistic one-pass-each logic with a lookup table:

```
declare -A lookup
while read key txt
do lookup["$key"]="$txt"
done < 2.txt

while read key txt
do echo "${lookup[$key]:-$txt}"
done < 1.txt
```